# Regex to match c# curly bracket line

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for the regex to match any string that has an opened or closed curly bracket. It should only match when there is another character besides space, tab, etc (\s) within the brackets - even if there is another bracket in the string.

Basicly this is part of a static code analyser witch should check if the bracket is on a new and blank line (style guide). If there is any other character in the string it should match.

I got this `^[\S]*({|})[\S]*$`. But it also matches `{` because of the `*`.
I am using C#.

Example:

Match: `{ lala`, `lala{`, `asdf{asdf`, `{}`

No Match: `{`, `{`, `}`,`TAB { TAB`, `asdf`

Thanks!

Comment: Strings " { lala" and " lala{ " have \s inside, so why they are ok for match?

Comment: \s' can occur in the string. But no other characters except ONE curly bracket (opend or closed). Maybe I descriped it badly. Sorry

Comment: I'm confused. So \s can occur if any charcter other than \s and {} occurs?

Comment: Are you looking to only match a string within brackets, e.g. `{hello}` would result in `hello`, and `{}` would result in no match? It looks like the examples described match your given regex `^[\S]*({|})[\S]*$`. Could you provide examples of what you want?

Comment: Why " {}" is okay then, when there is no other character, just brackets and space?

Comment: Imagen a code line in c# after e.g. a class name. There should be JUST ONE open curly bracket and maybe before or after this bracket some /s. Nothing else. No other character. I descriped this very baldy sorry

Comment: I have updated my answer, even I am not sure if now it is what your are looking for - take a look, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex `^(?=.*[{}])\S*$` would match string that contains at least one curly bracket and such string would not have any whitespace characters.

---

***Update:***

Based on you comments you might be looking for this regex: `.*{(?:\s*[^\s}]+}?|})`

Answer (score 0):

It's not very nice but this might work:

```
^([\S]+[{}])|([\S]+[{}][\S]+)|([{}][\S]+)$
```

Hope this helps